# StackOverflow Exception C# When MultiThreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I know why my exception is caused but cannot find a better way to fix this.
I tried everything so far but I don't get the same results I want without changing the method. The method Scrape(string link, Regex expression, Webclient webClient) returns a string list. This code works fine without multithreading, but the process of crawling is really slow on 1 thread. My goal is to have at least 15 threads running. (I tried increasing the stacksize as well)

```
 private void Crawl(List<String> links)
    {
        List<String> scrapedLinks = new List<String>();

        foreach (string link in links)
        {
            List<String> scrapedItems = Scrape(link, new Regex(iTalk_TextBox_Small2.Text), new WebClient());

            foreach (string item in scrapedItems) listBox1.Invoke(new Action(delegate () { listBox1.Items.Add(item); }));
            iTalk_Label4.Invoke(new Action(delegate () { iTalk_Label4.Text = "Scraped Items: " + listBox1.Items.Count; }));

            if (scrapedItems.Count > 0 || !Properties.Settings.Default.Inspector)
            {
                foreach (string scrapedLink in Scrape(link, new Regex(@"https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)"), new WebClient()))
                {
                    if(!Properties.Settings.Default.Blacklist.Contains(scrapedLink)) scrapedLinks.Add(scrapedLink);
                }
                scrapedLinksTotal += scrapedLinks.Count;                
            }

            iTalk_Label5.Invoke(new Action(delegate () { iTalk_Label5.Text = "Scraped Links: " + scrapedLinksTotal; }));
        }

        Crawl(scrapedLinks);
    }
```

Comment: Every single call to `Scrape` causes `scrapedLinks.Count` new calls to `Scrape`. Even if `scrapedLinks.Count` is not that big, you generate threads in an exponential way. Increasing the stack size won't help much, because multiplying it by the average size of `scrapedLinks.Count` will only get you one extra loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a terminal condition. Without delving into the logic of what Crawl actually does, perhaps something as simple as this will fix the problem:

```
private void Crawl(List<String> links)
{
    //////////////////////////////////
    // Check for something to work on
    if (links == null || links.Count == 0)
        return; // Return if there is nothing to do.
    //////////////////////////////////

    List<String> scrapedLinks = new List<String>();

    foreach (string link in links)
    {
        List<String> scrapedItems = Scrape(link, new Regex(iTalk_TextBox_Small2.Text), new WebClient());

        foreach (string item in scrapedItems) listBox1.Invoke(new Action(delegate () { listBox1.Items.Add(item); }));
        iTalk_Label4.Invoke(new Action(delegate () { iTalk_Label4.Text = "Scraped Items: " + listBox1.Items.Count; }));

        if (scrapedItems.Count > 0 || !Properties.Settings.Default.Inspector)
        {
            foreach (string scrapedLink in Scrape(link, new Regex(@"https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)"), new WebClient()))
            {
                if(!Properties.Settings.Default.Blacklist.Contains(scrapedLink)) scrapedLinks.Add(scrapedLink);
            }
            scrapedLinksTotal += scrapedLinks.Count;                
        }

        iTalk_Label5.Invoke(new Action(delegate () { iTalk_Label5.Text = "Scraped Links: " + scrapedLinksTotal; }));
    }

    Crawl(scrapedLinks);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stack overflow is caused by infinite recursion in 99% of cases. In your case you are calling Crawl(scrapedLinks) unconditionally inside Crawl. Don't know what scrapedLinks should do, but this is the reason.